# How to check the row & column of portlet in portlet layout

Tags: java, portlet, smartgwt

Using smartgwt, How to check the row & column of portlet in portlet layout
as I am creating a dashboard & I need to save the position of the portlets if changed through drag & drop, but I can't find any information in the portlet or the portal layout that gets it's row & column, any help?

```
Portlet portlet= new Portlet();
PortalLayout portalLayout = new PortalLayout();
portalLayout.addPortlet(portlet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
portlet.getPortalPosition().getColNum();
portlet.getPortalPosition().getRowNum();
```

Comment: I can't find getPortalPosition() in Portet

Comment: I am using Smart GWT 2.4, maybe that's the problem?
its irrelevant from the code, I just created a new Portlet & I can't find this methods.

Comment: I don't why but as far as I can remember this is second time that you're not willing to show your code. It's very important for you to understand that we cannot help you or any other person without code. We're not magician.

Comment: As I mentioned above, there is no code to show, I just created a new portlet and the methods above are not available.

Portlet portlet= new Portlet();
PortalLayout portalLayout = new PortalLayout();
portalLayout.addPortlet(portlet);